# Sonarqube analysis per commit(only the changes) before publishing the results to sonarqube dashboard.

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Is there anyway in sonarqube where we can run analysis on the files which have been changed by commit and get the code smells before publishing the code smells to sonar dashboard. Currently we have integrated the sonarqube analysis with Jenkins as a Job to run on a daily basis.

Comment: https://blog.sonarsource.com/putting-it-all-together-end-to-end-quality-with-sonarecosystem/

Comment: most of them there is a manual process of identifying the issues. what i expect is integrating with the CI pipeline. Analyzing only the changed files in the commit saves a lot of time.

Comment: @zeee have you read the part about the [GitHub plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin)? It seems a good fit for your purpose. You can get your pull requests analyzed before merging crap into master. It works incrementally, so if you push new commits to the branch, the changes get re-analyzed. Although you ask for per-commit checks, in my experience that's too granular and not very useful. As a branch should correspond to a feature, the per-PR analysis works very well in practice.

Comment: @janos we are using SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a nice answer in sonarQube site:

> You can get the list of changed files from the github api and then
> plug it into sonar.inclusions . Simple.
>
> In context to jenkins,
>
> 1. create a sonar.properties file (using shell)
> 2. make a github api
>    call and fetch the list of files changed with their api.
> 3. insert
>    the above fetched value inside the sonar.properties file
>    (sonar.inclusions=) (open file in write mode)
> 4. and pass this sonar
>    file to the build configuration (maven, ant etc)
>
> In this way , there would be new sonar inclusions for each PR in
> jenkins.